# Grepping parameters from lists of URLs

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Problem:

Grepping all parameters from a list of URLs

A link, for example,

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=grep+urls+from+a+file&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIL1008IL1008&oq=grep+urls+from+a+file
```

What I've tried:

Grepping any text that start with `?` and end with `=`, or start with `&` and end with `&` or empty string.

Desired outcome:

```
q

rlz

oq
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using grep with the `--perl-regexp` option :

```bash
grep -Po '(?<=(\?|&))[^&]*(?==)'
```

- `(?<=(\?|&))` A string that have `?` or `&` before
- `[^&]*` Any character but `&`
- `(?==)` A string that have `=` after

Comment: Doesn't work...

Comment: Could you be more specific ? What isn't working ? And could you tell me what version of grep you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your URL(s) are in the file called `file`:

```bash
sed -e 's/[^?]*[?]//' -e 's/=[^&]*//g' -e 'y/&/\n/' file
```

This first removes the part of the URL that comes before the first question mark, including the question mark itself.

After this first substitution, what's left of your example URL is

```
q=grep+urls+from+a+file&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIL1008IL1008&oq=grep+urls+from+a+file
```

The second substitution removes all parameter values, leaving the limiting `&` characters.  It removes every string starting with a `=` and consisting of non-`&`-characters.  With your example, this generates the following:

```
q&rlz&oq
```

The final expression replaces each `&` with a literal newline character:

```
q
rlz
oq
```